# Linksys E2000 (dd-wrt) DHCP in AP mode

Tags: router, dhcp, dd-wrt, switch, wifi-configuration

I have configured my Linksys E2000 Router as a switch via dd-wrt.

Devices connected by LAN:

- Samsung Smart TV
- ISP provided IPTV device
- Cable going to my actual Router (ISP provided, also the DHCP server)

WiFi is in AP mode (bridged, with WPA2 security), it should provide access to the internet over the ISP Router. I have turned DHCP completely off in dd-wrt.

Problem is, WiFi works great - for about 5 minutes or until I do an `ipconfig /renew`, then it crashes (no device can connect, existing device slowly disconnect, Internet stops working immediately) and only fixes itself after I reboot the router.

I have also tried DHCP forwarder mode. Sadly, I can't turn off DHCP on my ISP router...

And BTW, is there a way to access the web interface of that router? As soon as I connect it to the internet I loose access to it. Maybe also a DHCP error?

Comment: Have you made sure that all cables into the E2000 router are hosted in the LAN bays, **not** in the WAN bay (*i.e.*, the bay of the cable connecting to the Internet, if you used your router as a real router rather than a switch)?

Comment: I have checked "Assign WAN port to switch" as well, but yes, all cables are connected to acutal LAN ports.